# asp.net mvc: display a lightbox from a controller's action result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, popup, lightbox

I have an action that returns ViewResult (it's a detail form, `public ViewResult AddFoo(long id)` and I need to display this result in a lightbox

- My first idea was to generate a div with an iframe, but than I don't know how am I going to close (hide the div) this lightbox on submit
- Other thing that I could do is take somehow the generated html from the action (`from <body> to </body>`),  and put it inside the div instead of the iframe

How do you do this kind of stuff, I think there should a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, when you want to display a view in the context of another page, you return a `PartialViewResult` instead of a `ViewResult`. Then you can write JavaScript like:

```
$("#someDiv").load("/path/to/action");
```